# Transfer Dual Boot Drive to iMac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup

My mid 2009 MacBook Pro (refurbished in 2014 and 2016) has stopped turning on late 2020. It had over heating issues beforehand. However, it had a fusion drive that was relatively new.

It was a dual partition dual boot drive (Two different versions of OS X, Yosemite and El Capitan I believe). Two questions:

1. is it possible to remove said drive and install it into a replacement 2009 MacBook Pro?

And

2. If this transplant can work, how do I then clone both partitions (entire bootable drive) and transfer that entire image to 2015 iMac so I can avoid over heating issues when recording music?

Comment: Why not use a tool like `asr` or super duper or carbon copy cloner to clone the data onto the best drive that you install? Seems like two very different questions here

Comment: Your second transplant/clone may depend on the precise iMac model. Mid 2015 can boot to Yosemite, Late 2015 minimum OS is El Capitan.

Comment: Are you sure it has a fusion drive? That is a SSD and HDD presented to the system as one drive. Not sure MBP has them (perhaps you made your own) but if so you would have to split it first. See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207584

Comment: Yes, I installed the fusion drive into the 2009 MBP myself in 2016. It’s mostly HDD with partial SSD memory I believe, not sure of how it works. But it appeared as one drive when formatted. Then I divided it into two partitions.